# Finding remainder on division of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial which when divided by $x-3$ and $x-5$ leaves remainders $10$ and $6$ respectively. If $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)(x-5)$ then remainder is:

I assumed $P(x)=Q(x)\cdot (x-3)+10=R(x)\cdot (x-5)+6$ but it hasn't worked.

Any helpful answer will be appreciated by me.

Comment: looks like Chinese Reminder Theorem, see e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(x)=(x-3)(x-5)Q(x)+xA+B$
$P(3)=10=3A+B$
$P(5)=6=5A+B$

This gives $A=-2$,$B=16$

Thus by division by $(x-5)(x-3)$, ans will be $-2x+16$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $P(x)=G(x)(x-3)(x-5)+A(x-3)+B(x-5)$ where $A,B$  are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 0):

Using the *Chinese remainder theorem*, and the formula for solving a system of congruences mod $x-3$ and mod $x-5$:

A *Bézout's relation* between $x-3$ and $x-5$ is
$$\frac12\bigl((x-3)-(x-5)\bigr)=1$$
hence the remainder will be
$$R(x)=\frac12\bigl(6(x-3)-10(x-5)\bigr)=-2x+16$$

Note this is but the  *linear interpolation formula* between the points $(3,10)$  and $(5,6)$.